# Typescript Regex Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-typescript

I am using React for my frontend app. I have two different time format of data.
One is like this 08-10 and another one is like this 05:00-05:30. Most of the time format data is like this 08-10, few are like 05:00-05:30.
After getting the time date data, I used map function and pass to my time-format helper function, In my browser I want to display my data like this 05:00-05:30. My helper function works as expected but The problem is I am Typescript Error in my regex expression. It says `Object is possibly 'null'.` I used condition and as well optional-channing `?` but still getting Typescript. I don't know how to fix this Typescript error.

I shared my code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-sun-oyxlp?file=/src/App.tsx). You can see the Typescript error in there too.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

const toFourDigitTime = (time: string) => {
  if (time) {
    const expression = /(\d{2}):?(\d{2})?/;

    const [hours, minutes] = time?.match(expression).slice(1); // throws me Typescript error

    return `${hours.padStart(2, '0')}:${minutes ? minutes : '00'}`;
  }
};

export const toTimeRangeFormat = (range: string): string | undefined => {
 

  const [start, end] = range?.split('-');
  if (start && end) {
    return toFourDigitTime(start) + ' - ' + toFourDigitTime(end);
  }

  return range;
};

export default function App() {
  const [state] = React.useState(["08-10", "05:00-05:30"]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.map((i) => {
        return (
          <ul>
            <li>{toTimeRangeFormat(i)}</li>
          </ul>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It is because, that regular expression may have no match with the string you passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because match() returns null if no matches are found.

You need something like

```
const m = time.match(expression);
if (m) {
  const [hours, minutes] = m.split(1);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Still did not help.

Comment: I share my code in Codesandbox. You can test on my codesandbox

Comment: @Krisna this is more of a debugging help. farincz is correct. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value). What this error means is, some object maybe `null`. Now you are trying to `slice` which may also return an empty value.

Comment: use const [hours, minutes] = m.split(1); as in my post instead your const [hours, minutes] = time?.match(expression).slice(1);

Comment: and second error, not related to this question, needs "es2017" lib in tsconfig, then all compiles

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-pike-qgvp6?file=/src/App.tsx
changed lib to es2017, it works

Comment: Aaah sorry. But now it breaks the whole app :/ . `m.match is not a function`

Comment: time.match and then m.slice

Comment: I am using ` "es2019"` then why I am getting this error

Comment: Sorry! It was my mistake. stupid Typo. Thanks a lot Both of you